# Is this generic REST service a good idea?

Tags: rest, architecture, components

I have a question on whether or not a particular REST-service design is good or not.

The background is of having an inhouse monolithic system (will call this "the main system") dealing with e.g. customers. Then there are external components that have additional information on persons, which may or may not correspond 1-1 with a customer in the main system.

At present there is no definite specification of what kind of data is or may be associated with a person/customer in these external components.
The proposed design I have been presented with is a REST- service that exposes an API for the external system to call in order to feed the component with this arbitrary data associated with persons.
The idea is that by doing so the main system will have a single place to go to, to get the external data for customers/persons.
A proposed requirement of this REST service is that as new types of data is loaded into it by an external component, this data is automatically made accessible by the service, without it needing to be changed in any way, or redeployed. And "new data" generally means a new type of key value set. E.g. initially the service might provide data for customer identified by a customerId. Then an external component decides to post some kind of data associated to SSN. This should automatically entail that the service can be queried for this data by supplying SSN in the request.

In order to avoid the need to change/redeploy the service I’m assuming the solution will ahve to have a very generic scheme of reference, e.g.
http://url/generic-resource-name/?id=[customerId]&keyType=cusomterId
There is really nothing in the requirements that limits the data to be associated to a person, only that it’s key be made up of one value.

And example use case sequence could be:
[image]

So to the question:
Is it a good idea to implement such a general purpose service? And how does it rhyme with the principles of REST: the noun in question that the service will operate on will have to be very generic, really nothin short of “resource” or “data”, which in itself seems like a smell to me.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have gone one step too generic.  If your REST service is literally going to be a key/value store, then maybe you can use an off the shelf key/value store.

Comment: Right, thanks. Any suggestion on candidates for such an of the shelf key value store? Preferably such that it comes with an easy to set up REST api that would more or less meet the needs I described?

Answer (score 0):

> So to the question: Is it a good idea to implement such a general
>   purpose service?

I believe not. You are going straight into [Inner platform effect antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). You must be very careful, or you might end like [Vision](https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/).

Please also read a chapter "The allure of distributed objects" from Fowler's [PoEAA book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vqTfNFDzzdIC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=fowler+sucks+like+an+inverted+hurricane&source=bl&ots=oSDoAxNUqA&sig=yFQe5k9eVklx1bTLPmfQ7-coRq8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9-6mn2abJAhVq7nIKHVy5DqsQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=fowler%20sucks%20like%20an%20inverted%20hurricane&f=false). Just to be careful.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting and entertaining read about Vision. 
I kind of agree, but not completely since the REST service wouldn't be an Inner thing. Rather something platform independent.

Comment: @tyronecopex Of course, you know better since this is your system and I might miss something. Please also read a chapter "The allure of distributed objects" from Fowler's [PoEAA book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vqTfNFDzzdIC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=fowler+sucks+like+an+inverted+hurricane&source=bl&ots=oSDoAxNUqA&sig=yFQe5k9eVklx1bTLPmfQ7-coRq8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9-6mn2abJAhVq7nIKHVy5DqsQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=fowler%20sucks%20like%20an%20inverted%20hurricane&f=false). Just to be careful.